# What does methods::slotNames do with non-class, non-character args?

Tags: r, class

> Usage: slotNames(x)

The man page says

> If given an argument that is neither a character string nor a class
> definition, slotNames (only) uses class(x) instead.
> But I experimented:

```
Rgames> foo <- 'whatever'
Rgames> slotNames(foo)
character(0)    #as expected
Rgames> foo <- sin
Rgames> slotNames(foo)
NULL
Rgames> class(foo)
[1] "function"
Rgames> bar <- list(a = 1, b= 2)
Rgames> slotNames(bar)
NULL
Rgames> class(bar)
[1] "list"
```

Am I misinterpreting the meaning of that description of the input argument `x` ?

Comment: What exactly were you expecting as output? Where you expecting `slotNames(bar)` to return "list"? But cause "list" is not a slot name for `bar`. And a `list` type doesn't have any slots. It's not an S4 class.

Comment: `.slotNames` is just returning `names(getClassDef(class(x))@slots)`.  If the `slots` slot is an empty list, then the `names` attribute is `NULL`.  Probably `.slotNames` should return `NULL` instead of `character(0L)` for classes without definitions, to be consistent with the documentation.

Comment: @MrFlick  I was expecting the output to default to the output provided by `class(x)` .  As I wrote, I may be misinterpreting what the quoted part of the man page says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`slotNames` is meant for use with S4 classes. For example:

```r
setClass("myS4class", slots = c(x = "numeric", y = "numeric"))

getSlots("myS4class")
#>         x         y 
#> "numeric" "numeric"
```

If you look at the source code for `slotNames`, we have:

```r
function (x) {
  if (is(x, "classRepresentation")) names(x@slots) else .slotNames(x)
}
```

This will always call the function `.slotNames` unless `x` is a `"classRepresentation"` object as might be returned from `getClass("myS4class")`.

If we look at the source for `.slotNames`, we see:

```r
function (x) 
{
    classDef <- getClassDef(
      if (!isS4(x) && is.character(x) && length(x) == 1L) x else class(x)
    )
    if (is.null(classDef)) 
        character()
    else names(classDef@slots)
}
```

This means that if we pass something like `sin`, we get a formalized S4 class definition for the class `"function"`

```r
foo <- sin
foo_class_def <- getClassDef(class(foo))
```

This formal class definition looks like this:

```r
foo_class_def
#> Class "function" [package "methods"]
#> 
#> No Slots, prototype of class "function"
#> 
#> Extends: "OptionalFunction", "PossibleMethod"
#> 
#> Known Subclasses: 
#> Class "classGeneratorFunction", from data part
#> Class "MethodDefinition", from data part
#> Class "genericFunction", from data part
#> Class "functionWithTrace", from data part
#> Class "activeBindingFunction", from data part
#> Class "refMethodDef", from data part
#> Class "derivedDefaultMethod", by class "MethodDefinition", distance 2
#> Class "MethodWithNext", by class "MethodDefinition", distance 2
#> Class "SealedMethodDefinition", by class "MethodDefinition", distance 2
#> Class "MethodDefinitionWithTrace", by class "MethodDefinition", distance 2
#> Class "standardGeneric", by class "genericFunction", distance 2
#> Class "nonstandardGenericFunction", by class "genericFunction", distance 2
#> Class "groupGenericFunction", by class "genericFunction", distance 2
#> Class "genericFunctionWithTrace", by class "genericFunction", distance 2
#> Class "defaultBindingFunction", by class "activeBindingFunction", distance 2
#> Class "internalDispatchMethod", by class "MethodDefinition", distance 3
#> Class "MethodWithNextWithTrace", by class "MethodDefinition", distance 3
#> Class "derivedDefaultMethodWithTrace", by class "MethodDefinition", distance 3
#> Class "nonstandardGroupGenericFunction", by class "genericFunction", distance 3
#> Class "standardGenericWithTrace", by class "genericFunction", distance 3
#> Class "groupGenericFunctionWithTrace", by class "genericFunction", distance 3
#> Class "refMethodDefWithTrace", by class "refMethodDef", distance 2
#> Class "externalRefMethod", by class "refMethodDef", distance 2
#> Class "refObjectGenerator", by class "classGeneratorFunction", distance 2
```

This has named slots, so the slot names returned by `.slotNames` is `NULL`

```r
names(foo_class_def@slots)
#> NULL
```

However, if `foo` is a length-1 character, as in your first example, `.slotNames` will assume it is a class name and try to look up its class definition.

```r
foo <- "whatever"
foo_class_def <- getClassDef(foo)
foo_class_def
#> NULL
```

We can see that this will cause `.slotNames` to return `character(0)` instead of `NULL`.

I do wonder if, for consistency, the function should return `NULL` in this situation.

Answer (score 2):

The `slotNames` function is for interacting with S4 objects. It doesn't work well with arbitrary objects. Using this example

```
setClass("track", slots = c(x="numeric", y="numeric"))
myTrack <- new("track", x = -4:4, y = exp(-4:4))

slotNames("track")             #[A]
# [1] "x" "y"
slotNames(getClass("track"))   #[B]
# [1] "x" "y"
slotNames(myTrack)             #[C]
# [1] "x" "y"
slotNames(class(myTrack))      #[D]
# [1] "x" "y"
```

The [A] part is using the character string. The [B] part is using the class representation. The [C] part is where it calls `class()` on the object so it's equivalent to [D]. So that part in the description for the parameter means it will call `class()` on the passed object to get the class name, not that it will return the same results as if calling `class()` on the object. It should always return slot names if available, and the class name would not be a valid slot name.